# Reading AFNetworking response headers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, afnetworking

I'm trying to figure out how to read the response headers from a AFNetworking request?

Is it possible in the following snippet, or do I need to take another approach?

```
// Create client
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"]];

// Send request
[client getPath:@"/test" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){

}];
```

Comment: Perhaps the header that you need you can extract from the response object? You should typecast the response object to an NSHTTPURLResponse object to get values like the HTTP status code. It also has a method called `-allHeaderFields`. More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I don't think this is quite right since the response object that you are referring to is the response of the request and not necessarily an instance of NSHTTPURLResponse.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use the response property (not the response object of the block) of the AFHTTPRequestOperation instance that is available in both the success and failure blocks.

This response object is an instance of [NSHTTPURLResponse](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and you can send it a message of  `allHeaderFields` to fetch all the headers of your request.

Comment: Perfect! This solved it for me, thank you!

In my case [[operation response] allHeaderFields] got me what I wanted

Comment: This is kind of opaque.  Would either of you like to expand on this topic, perhaps explaining the mechanics a bit?  As someone new to AFNetworking, I'm having some difficulty understanding how to access the reachability status and implement appropriate code.

Comment: If anyone's wondering how to do it: here's the said `AFHTTPRequestOperation` object as `AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation`. And to get the http header info into, declare a variable of `NSDictionary` and `operation.response.allHeaderFields`. Then you can print it out using `NSLog` like this, `dictionary.description`.

Comment: if the http head has two same key , I cannot get all info

Answer (score 6):

Quite simply, since the accepted answer doesn't actually have an example:

```
[operationInstance setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
       NSLog(@"%@", operation.response.allHeaderFields);
}];
```

Answer (score 4):

I was not able to resolve it by 
`[[operation response] allHeaderFields]` or `operation.response.allHeaderFields` ,
 as it gave compilation error.

I just typecasted it to `(NSDictionary *)` and access the key values as

`[[(NSDictionary *)operation valueForKey: @"response"] valueForKey: @"allHeaderFields"]`

Comment: Since SO won't allow edits under 7 characters the typo above can't be fixed.  How silly is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *responseheaders = [HTTPResponse allHeaderFields];
NSString *newtoken = [responseheaders valueForKey:@"Authorization"];
```